# What timezone is Opportunity CloseDate stored in?

Tags: opportunity, timezone, closedate

I am working specifically with Opportunities, but I assume that all closeDates are stored the same in SF.

If an Opportunity is closed at 10pm EST, March 4th; the time is 3am March 5th in UTC. Does Salesforce store the closed date as 2014-03-04 or 2014-03-05? And what timezone is that date for?

If your brain hurts, mine does too. I'm ready for [Stardate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stardate).

[image: timezone example]

Image from: http://www.worldtimebuddy.com/utc-to-est-converter

Answer (score 1):

Date/Time data is stored in UTC but presented to the user on their own timezone. The format used to present the data is based on the user locale.

Comment: Right, but a date does not have any time associated with it, only year-month-day. How can you convert something without hours from one timezone to the other.

Comment: I assume the same rule will apply and the internal reference to this date will be as the date value plus 00h:00m:00s. You can easily test this by setting up users with different timezones.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like closed date is timezone agnostic.

I came to this conclusion by performing the following test:
I changed the timezone of my SF Org from EST to Sidney EST. I also changed my account timezone to Sidney EST. 
I then created a new Opportunity, and set the date to Mar 06, 2014 (today in Sidney EST, even though it is Mar 05, 2014 in EST). I then retrieved that record using Apex and found the opportunity to contain the following values:

```
LastModifiedDate:2014-03-05T16:02:20.000+0000
SystemModstamp:2014-03-05T16:02:20.000+0000
CreatedDate:2014-03-05T16:02:20.000+0000
CloseDate:2014-03-06
```

As you can see, the datetime objects are stored in utc, and the close date is stored as it was entered by the user (timezone agnostic). 
I then changed the timezone associated with my account and with my sf org back to EST. I then viewed the opportunity I created, and the closed date still read: 2014-03-06.

Here is the timezone data:
[image]

And [here is how you can change the timezone of your account/org](https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=90630000000go5vAAA).